# Bold and italic at the same time (beamer)

Tags: beamer, bold, italic

How can I make some text bold and italic at the same time (in the beamer class)? This example does **not** seem to work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\begin{document}
\frame{
    A number is \textbf{\textit{x}-smooth} if ...\\
    A number is \textbf{\emph{x}-smooth} if ...
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Load a font that has the combination `bf+it`, e.g.

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\frame{
    A number is \textbf{\textit{x}-smooth} if ...\\
    A number is \textbf{\emph{x}-smooth} if ...
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

LaTeX gives you a hint:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/bx/it' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmss/bx/n' instead on input line 7.
```

and in fact if you use T1 the combination is available, add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Answer (score 3):

The font shape combination bold/italic is also available if you use `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bm}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\begin{document}
\frame{
    A number is \textbf{x-smooth} if ...\\
    A number is \textbf{\emph{x}-smooth} if ...\\
    A number is \textbf{$\bm{x}$-smooth} if ...
}
\end{document}
```

Note though, that if you write `x-smooth` the `x` should probably better be in math mode (imagine you need `$x^2$-smooth` or `$\sin(x)$-smooth`), so you could use `\textbf{$\bm{x}$-smooth}` for bold math (variables in math mode are automatically set in italics).